# Conormal exact sequence

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory, schemes, sheaf-cohomology, tangent-bundle

Let $X$ be a smooth variety and $Y\subset X$ a smooth subvariety with ideal sheaf $\mathcal{I}_{Y/X}$.

For $n\geq 2$ is there an analogue of the exact sequence
$$0\rightarrow \mathcal{I}_{Y/X}/\mathcal{I}_{Y/X}^{2}\rightarrow\Omega_{X|Y}\rightarrow\Omega_Y\rightarrow 0$$
involving $\mathcal{I}_{Y/X}^n/\mathcal{I}_{Y/X}^{n+1}$?

Answer (score 3):

In general, when there is an exact sequence of vector bundles

$$0\to A\to B\to C\to 0,\label{1}\tag{1}$$

there is an associated long exact sequence

$$0\to S^kA\to S^{k-1}A\otimes B\to S^{k-2}A\otimes \wedge^2B\to \cdots\to \wedge^kB\to \wedge^k C\to 0\label{2}\tag{2}$$
for each $k\ge 1$, where $S^k$ is to take the $k$-th symmetric power. The map on the right is to take $\wedge^k$ of $B\to C$, while others are contraction of $A\to B$. See [[Gr94, Lecture 4](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/b52495)]. For example, when $k=3$, the second map from the left $$S^2A\otimes B\to A\otimes \wedge^2B$$ is give by $a_1\otimes a_2\otimes b+a_2\otimes a_1\otimes b\mapsto a_1\otimes (a_2\wedge b)+a_2\otimes(a_1\wedge b)$.

In particular, apply to the conormal exact sequence

$$0\to N_{Y|X}^*\to \Omega_{X|Y}\to \Omega_Y\to 0,$$

and use the fact that $S^k(N^*_{Y|X})=S^k(I_{Y}/I^2_{Y})=I_{Y}^k/I^{k+1}_{Y}$, one has the following exact sequence
$$0\to I_{Y}^k/I^{k+1}_{Y}\to I_{Y}^{k-1}/I^{k}_{Y}\otimes \Omega_{X|Y}\to I_{Y}^{k-2}/I^{k-1}_{Y}\otimes \wedge^2\Omega_{X|Y}\to \cdots\to \wedge^k\Omega_{X|Y}\to \wedge^k \Omega_Y\to 0.$$

**Edited:** As pointed out by ([@Yai0Phah](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/23875/yai0phah), there is another long exact sequence, called Koszul sequence, associated to \eqref{1} (which only need the flatness assumption of $A,B,C$):

$$0\to S^kA\to S^kB\to S^{k-1}B\otimes C\to \cdots \to B\otimes \wedge^{k-1}C\to \wedge^kC\to 0.$$
See the second exact sequence in [[Ill71, I.1.4.3.1.7, p.110](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/BFb0059052)] and use the isomorphism of graded symmetric algebra to the graded divided power algebra. So you get another long exact sequence involving $I_{Y}^k/I^{k+1}_{Y}$ by applying to the conormal sequence.

[Gr94] Green, Mark L. Infinitesimal methods in Hodge theory. In *Algebraic cycles and Hodge theory* (Torino, 1993), Springer, Berlin, 1994.

[Il71] Illusie, Luc.
Complexe cotangent et déformations. I.
Lecture Notes in Mathematics, Vol. 239. Springer-Verlag, Berlin-New York, 1971. xv+355 pp.

Comment: Since $Y$ is a subvariety of $X$, all of your restricted cotangent bundles should read $\Omega_{X|Y}$.

Comment: This holds for all exact sequences of flat modules. I think that this is called the Koszul sequence and should be found in Illusie's thesis.

Comment: @TabesBridges Thanks, typo fixed.

Comment: @Yai0Phah Thanks for bring up the Koszul sequence. I added another reference of Green. (It doesn't seem to be in Illusie's thesis as I searched.)

Comment: It is in Illusie's thesis ('70) §I.4.3.1 and in particular Prop I.4.3.1.6, so earlier than the references that you gave. By the way, there is another one, also called Koszul, in §V.4.1.7 (the first Roman number is the chapter number). Maybe this could be also found in Quillen's MIT notes ('60) on cotangent complexes, but it is unpublished.

Comment: @Yai0Phah Thanks for helping to find the referece! The exact sequences in Prop. I.4.3.1.6 is written explicitly in the same page below, and it reads: $$0\to \wedge^k A\to \wedge^{k-1}A\otimes B\to \cdots \to A\otimes S^{k-1}B\to S^kB\to S^kC.$$ It is still different from the the exact sequence in my answer. Can one be derived from the other?

Comment: The canonical map from the graded symmetric algebra to the graded divided power algebra of a module is an isomorphism in char 0.

Comment: @Yai0Phah Sorry, I don't get the punchline, what does $S^k(V)\cong \Gamma^k(V)$ for $V$ a vector bundle imply in this content? (I don't see how divided power algebra is involved in the discussion.)

Comment: Prop I.4.3.6 has two conclusions, one with symmetric algebras, and the other with PD algebras. Use the one with PD and the isomorphism of Sym and PD.

Comment: @Yai0Phah Thanks! That sequence is different from the sequence I got from Green, but I edited the answer and kept the both.